# How to express redirect to a specific router page in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have `router.get("/verify", HANDLER HERE)` to verify the user and the following to serve the Angular index.html file to the user.

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));});
```

Now, /verify?token=TOKEN_HERE accepts a token, verified the user account in the database and then redirects the user to the angular application. I want to be able to redirect the user to a specific page in angular which is **/login** and  that too with a message like **"Your account has been verified. Please login".**

The problem is that no matter to which page I redirect, the index file opens the homepage itself and I am not sure how to send that message.

Aim:

1. Redirect the user to a specific router page in angular.
2. Send a message along with that redirect.

Comment: in `HANDLER HERE` do a redirect to `/login`, if you want a message your need to store it in a state of sorts either serverside and fetch state when loading login page or pass as a param like /login?verified and then render the message in good faith it was set by the server

Comment: I am not sure if I get that entirely. On dev, my angular runs on port 4200 while server on 3000. All these bits are confusing me.
I belive the redirect won;t work here? Please ignore this comment. I am working on what you said.

Comment: How do I serve my angular app on port 3000 on development server?
```res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))``` serves only the ```ng build--prod``` version. How do I make the server serve the dev version in dev environment?